# Is injection attack possible on the following code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, sql-injection

I have to create two applications for every web app attack type for my project.
One in which the attack works, other in which it doesn't.
At the time of writing code for sql injection, i cam out with the following codes:

### vulnerable

```
EmpTable result = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<EmpTable>("Select * from EmpTable where username = '" + TxtUsername.Text + "'and password = '" + TxtPassword.Text + "'").FirstOrDefault();
```

### and, invulnerable:

```
EmpTable result = (from reff in ctx.EmpTables.Where(p => (p.Username == TxtUsername.Text) && (p.Password == TxtPassword.Text)) select reff).FirstOrDefault();
```

i just want to make sure that there is no way to perform injection attack on the invulnerable one.
**Please tell me if the code is really invulnerable.**

Comment: I believe LINQ converts queries into paramterised SQL therefore you should be safe from SQL injection.

Comment: The LinqToSQL engine with generate parameters for you in the second version, so it should be ok

Comment: Besides sql injection, it is never never a good idea to store passwords in a plain text format and then perform simple string comparison. In cases where the database is compromised, all passwords of your clients will be revealed. Instead, store SHA-256 or better hashes of passwords, and then compare hashing results from database and from user interface.

Comment: Are their any drawbacks of using LINQ? why do people use sql in most applications?

Comment: I think it is mostly based on habits and existing knowledge of programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the second case, I believe that is invulnerable, because you pass the responsability to LINQ (and Entity Framework, or NHibernate, or other ORM tools like this) to performance the query on database. It should have to deal with your SQL safely since it provides this task.

In the first case, you should use [`Parameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to avoid SQL Injection, for sample:

```
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"select * from EmpTable where username = @user and password = @pass", 
                                new SqlParameter("user", TxtUsername.Text), 
                                new SqlParameter("pass", TxtPassword.Text));
```

*Obs: I didn't try it*

Comment: Please can you tell how to implement parameter on the first code